# Rails 6 doesn't output the result of system tests (with rails test:system)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

My Rails application doesn't output the result of the system tests (no failures, no assertions, nothing). The funny thing is that I can see chrome doing what it was expected to do (filling fields, etc...), but when the test is finished, no output on the shell, just the following:

```
francesco.mari@MB68D:DemographicsMapper (inline_mapping_editing *) $ bin/rails test:system
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.8 (ruby 2.6.6-p146), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
* Environment: test
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:49330
Use Ctrl-C to stop
francesco.mari@MB68D:DemographicsMapper (inline_mapping_editing *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue was on the file `test_helper.rb`. After I added the line `parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors)` it worked as it should.

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  #...
  parallelize(workers: :number_of_processors) # added this line
  #...
end
```